# AngularJS & Protractor - getLocationAbsUrl() doesn't return the url (string) but an object

Tags: angularjs, protractor

The title is saying it all.
I want to log the url to a console but it gives me some object

spec.js

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {

  it('should add 1 and 2', function() {

    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/#/');
    element(by.model('first')).sendKeys(1);
    element(by.model('second')).sendKeys(2);

    element(by.id('gobutton')).click();

    console.log(browser.getLocationAbsUrl()); // logs some object

    expect(browser.getLocationAbsUrl())
        .toEqual('/'); 
    });

});
```

And this is what I seen in my console

```
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started
{ closure_uid_727700741: 274,
  flow_:
   { events_: {},
     closure_uid_727700741: 1,
     activeFrame_:
      { events_: {},
        closure_uid_727700741: 75,
        flow_: [Circular],
        parent_: [Object],
        children_: [Object],
        lastInsertedChild_: [Object],
        pendingTask_: null,
        isLocked_: false,
        isBlocked_: false,
        pendingCallback: false,
        pendingRejection: false,
        cancellationError_: null },
     schedulingFrame_:
      { events_: {},
        closure_uid_727700741: 75,
        flow_: [Circular],
        parent_: [Object],
        children_: [Object],
        lastInsertedChild_: [Object],
        pendingTask_: null,
        isLocked_: false,
        isBlocked_: false,
        pendingCallback: false,
        pendingRejection: false,
        cancellationError_: null },
     shutdownTask_: null,
     eventLoopTask_: null,
     hold_:
      { _idleTimeout: 2147483647,
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idleStart: 95289669,
        _onTimeout: [Function: wrapper],
        _repeat: true },
     yieldCount_: 10 },
  stack_: null,
  parent_:
   { closure_uid_727700741: 272,
     flow_:
      { events_: {},
        closure_uid_727700741: 1,
        activeFrame_: [Object],
        schedulingFrame_: [Object],
        shutdownTask_: null,
        eventLoopTask_: null,
        hold_: [Object],
        yieldCount_: 10 },
     stack_: { [Task: Protractor.getLocationAbsUrl()] name: 'Task' },
     parent_: null,
     callbacks_: [ [Object] ],
     state_: 'pending',
     handled_: true,
     pendingNotifications_: false,
     value_: undefined },
  callbacks_: null,
  state_: 'pending',
  handled_: false,
  pendingNotifications_: false,
  value_: undefined }
.


1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 3.251 seconds
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 passed
```

What is that object ?
How can I print the current url to a console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know `browser.getLocationAbsUrl()` return the promise and when the promise is resolve it will give you the current url.
Therefore while you are printing it with

```
console.log(browser.getLocationAbsUrl());
```

It prints the complete object of promise.

Try out the code below it may help you :-

```
 browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(actualUrl) {
      console.log(actualUrl);
    });
```

you can find the syntax here [link](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/tutorial/step_06/#test)

Hope it helps :)